# Analysing with SonarQube causes 0 files indexed and no reports (Maven Project)

Tags: java, maven, report, sonarqube

I have some trouble using SonarQube on an extern server. I'm working with SonarQube just for a couple days now and when I analyze my Maven project local everything is working fine. We are using a Postgresql database.
But there are some problems when I try to analyze a project on an extern SonarQube server.

### The Environment:

I'm using SonarQube 4.4 and Maven 3.3. Please find my Maven settings.xml down below.

```
  <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties> 
            <sonar.jdbc.url>
              jdbc:postgresql://databaseadress/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
            </sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>username</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>password</sonar.jdbc.password>                
            <sonar.host.url>
              http://hostAdress
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

I already added the correct database connection. I set up the SonarQoube server by myself and the sonar.propterties was changed correctly.The project is written in Java.
Running an analysis it connects to the database and it starts analysing.

### The Problem:

If I analyze the project with `mvn sonar:sonar` I get the following message:

> ...
>   INFO: SonarQube Server 4.4
>   [INFO] [17:07:01.958] Load global settings 
>   [INFO] [17:07:02.137] User cache: C:\Users\christian.braun.sonar\cache
>   [INFO] [17:07:02.142] Install plugins
>   [INFO] [17:07:02.159] Install JDBC driver
>   [INFO] [17:07:02.163] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://databaseadress
> /sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
>   [INFO] [17:07:02.229] Initializing Hibernate
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.077] Loading technical debt model...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.089] Loading technical debt model done: 12 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.090] Load project settings
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.170] Apply project exclusions
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.257] -------------  Scan TestMaven
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.259] Load module settings
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.394] Loading rules...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.403] Loading rules done: 9 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.415] Configure Maven plugins
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.444] Compare to previous analysis (2014-09-02)
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.445] Compare over 30 days (2014-08-03, analysis of 2014-09-02 15:58:02.965)
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.446] No quality gate is configured.
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.461] Base dir: E:\WORKSPACE_TEST\1
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.461] Working dir: E:\WORKSPACE_TEST\1\target\sonar
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.461] Source dirs: E:\WORKSPACE_TEST\1\src\main\java
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.461] Test dirs: E:\WORKSPACE_TEST\1\src\test\java
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.461] Binary dirs: E:\WORKSPACE_TEST\1\target\classes
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.461] Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: de_DE
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.461] **Index files**
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.483] **0 files indexed**
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.486] Sensor QProfileSensor...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.495] Sensor QProfileSensor done: 9 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.495] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.503] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 8 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.503] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.514] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 11 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.515] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.523] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 8 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.523] Sensor FileHashSensor...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.524] Sensor FileHashSensor done: 1 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.524] Sensor CpdSensor...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.524] Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.524] Sensor Maven dependencies...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.554] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 30 ms
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.660] Execute decorators...
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.740] Store results in database
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.782] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse `http://hostAdress/dashboard/index/1:1`
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.879] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.880] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.897] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.904] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2014-08-05 and 2014-09-01
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.905] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2013-09-03 and 2014-08-05
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.905] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2009-09-08 and 2013-09-03
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.905] -> Delete data prior to: 2009-09-08
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.908] -> Clean TestMaven [id=5]
>   [INFO] [17:07:04.911] <- Clean snapshot 9
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 15.234 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-02T17:07:04+02:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/76M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Looks good at first sight but Sonar doesn't find any files.  0 files indexed
When I take a look at SonarQube I discover the project folder but there are no reports.

### Question:

What could be the problem that Sonar doesn't index any files?
I read that this problem could go with the missing sonar-runner, but the SonarQube Documentation says that there is no need of the Sonar-Runner while using the Maven-Plugin.
Just to make this clear, the project is not on the same mashine as sonarqube. Does this matter for indexing files?
Please consider that I'm a complete newbie to SonarQube

Best regards

Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i fixed the problem. SonarQube was just missing the needed plugins. I didn't had to do that using SonarQube on my localhost. After installing them through `settings->Update Center` everything worked fine. As I said this was a greenhorn mistake.

Comment: settings - update center? I dont have that setting option